# Debug apk ionic & see the errors

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk

I generated apk from ionic and when testing it on emulator it works but on device it bugs how to see the bugs and errors on apk ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have USB debugging turned on in the developer settings?
installing apk on device and try to debug it use this [chrome://inspect/#devices](http://chrome://inspect/#devices)
but make sure that mobile is connected with USB then you can debug your app.

try to follow this blog [debug app](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1030830/Debug-Ionic-Android-Application-On-Mobile-Devices)

Comment: Thanks but i'm talking about the signed apk not the one generated from 'ionic cordova run android' but from 'ionic build android --prod --release'

Comment: yes you can just open apk from mobile and in chrome browser open the chrome://inspect/#devices link. here you will get help http://legacy.docs.ionic.io/docs/chrome-inspector

Comment: sir i checked but file are not loaded after inspect

Answer (score 0):

you can use `chrome://inspect/#devices`

The Chrome Inspector can be used to debug your app on a physical Android device or emulator, just like it can be used on any web application.

you most enable developer mod on mobile and connect devise to computer

Comment: weird thing happend with me... my app works just fine at google inspector, but when i generate the APK and try to run it from apk i just cant install...

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you can use the Logcat to see all events on device:

```
adb logcat | grep SystemWebChromeClient
```